# Radio Buttons not Pre-populating if there is an Existing Record

Tags: php, mysqli

This is a simple application with a form with 3 questions. Each question has 2 options. If a user has previously submitted answers, then the form should pre-populate, but for some reason, it is not.

Here's the code. Any help or guidance is GREATLY appreciated.

```
<?php

    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $anthem1 = '';
    $cointoss2 = '';
    $firstscore3 = ''; 

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        if (isset($_POST['anthem1'])) {

            $anthem1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['anthem1']);
        }       

        if (isset($_POST['cointoss2'])) {
             $cointoss2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['cointoss2']);
        }       

        if (isset($_POST['firstscore3'])) {
             $firstscore3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['firstscore3']);
        }


        $query = "INSERT INTO mypicks (user_id, anthem1, cointoss2, firstscore3) 
                      VALUES ('{$user_id}','{$anthem1}','{$cointoss2}','{$firstscore3}')
                      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE anthem1 = '{$anthem1}',
                      cointoss2 = '{$cointoss2}',
                      firstscore3 = '{$firstscore3}'";


        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    }


    $query = "SELECT * FROM mypicks WHERE user_id = {$user_id}";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if($result->num_rows == 1) {

        $user_picks = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        $anthem1 = $user_picks['anthem1'];
        $cointoss2 = $user_picks['cointoss2'];
        $firstscore3 = $user_picks['firstscore3'];
    }

?>
```

Here's the form (one question from it):

```
<form action="Game1_MyPicks.php" method="post">

Will the National Anthem be over 3 mins and 15 secs? <br />
Over  <input type="radio" name="anthem1" value="Over" <?php if ($anthem1=="Over") print('checked="checked"') ?>/><br />
Under <input type="radio" name="anthem1" value="Under" <?php if ($anthem1=="Under") print('checked="checked"') ?>/><br />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name= "anthem1" value="" <?php if ($anthem1) echo "checked";?>>
```

Comment: Yeah, I have similar code in the forml, but still not working. I just added the form code as well.

Comment: Just added it jophab.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form action="Game1_MyPicks.php" method="post">

Will the National Anthem be over 3 mins and 15 secs? <br />
Over  <input type="radio" name="anthem1" value="Over" <?php if ($anthem1=="Over") print("checked"); ?>/><br />
Under <input type="radio" name="anthem1" value="Under" <?php if ($anthem1=="Under") print("checked"); ?>/><br />

</form>
```